# What is ajax gets invalid form, How can i render it?

Tags: django, ajax, django-ajax-selects

I am working with Django and Ajax.
With the help of jQuery, i successfully sent **form data** to server and able to validate it.

Problem arrive when form is invalid, i want that, if the form is invalid, ajax get the **invalid form** and render it to same template with errors like all invalid forms do.

How Can i do it ?

Comment: Update question with code.

Answer (score 0):

The closest method you can do is to return [Form.errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/). For example:

```
def submitSample(request):
    form = SampleForm(request.POST)
    response_data = {}

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        response_data['result'] = 1
    else:
        response_data['result'] = 0
        response_data['errors'] = form.errors

    return HttpResponse(response_data)
```

The `response_data['errors']` will contain a dictionary of error messages like:

```
{'title':['This field is required.']}
```

After sending the ajax request, you can use jQuery to display the errors on the form elements. Note that you will have to find a way to append the error messages next to their elements.